# Tag choice displayed in browser title bar

Tags: discussion, tagging

Consider the following question: [APA6 Class - Single-spaced Tables for Manuscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44013/5764)

[image]

In terms of tags, it lists under [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables), [floats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats), [line-spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-spacing), [apa6](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apa6) in that specific rank order (as seen on the RHS). The title bar (when viewed from within Google Chrome) displays

[image]

suggesting that the [floats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats) tag is somehow important. What is the motivation behind choosing [floats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats) above the other three? Obviously it's not alphabetical (due to [apa6](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apa6)) nor based on rank.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most popular tag, which means the tag with the most questions, is added to the title, for SEO reasons. If the tag is already contained in the question title, it's omitted and the next one is chosen - better than repeating it.

That's the case here: the most popular tag [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) is already part of the title (as apa6 too), so the next one in rank is chosen: [floats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats).

Related questions on meta.SE:

- [Why is the first tag sometimes in the  tag of some questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions)
- [Which tag is added to the page title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/which-tag-is-added-to-the-page-title)